# Page inspector: No mapping data was returned from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, page-inspector

I have a Web Forms application in .NET 3.5 that I am maintaining in VS 2013.  It neither runs nor loads in page inspector.

I have gone through various StOvf questions.  Thanks to those I have done:

- Changed the target framework from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0
- Added references to `Microsoft.CSharp` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, as the project imports Excel spreadsheets.
- Installed Shared Management Objects, as the project runs on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Having worked through previous errors, I am now up to Page Inspector complaining:  "No mapping data was returned from the server".  The web browser complaining: "XML Parsing Error: no element found".

A plain HTML page has the same error in Page Inspector, but no error message in the browser.  It's just blank.

How do I get my project to run?

ETA 4 August to bump the question.
I presently suspect that the issue involves user authentication (a point I had not reached when I originally asked the question).  The application is supposed to read the user from MS Windows on the client via `UserSecurity.CurrentUser.Identity`.  However, this is null during application startup.

In the application property window (NOT Project->Properties), `Anonymous Authentication` is enabled and `Windows Authentication` is disabled.  In one testbed I reversed both settings.  That application pops up a system login dialog and then properly authenticates the user.  But the design intent is to not have this popup.

Edit 2:  Windows authentication works properly if I comment out the `security` node under `system.webServer`.  This does not affect the original question, why did a null page show up instead of the project's "access denied" page?  And the secondary question remains, why is there a login popup at all?

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem, I commented my .aspx file part-by-part and found out what caused the problem. It was an `OnClick=` property calling a non-existing code-behind funtion. How? I had changed it's name (with refactor->rename option from code-behind) and vs2013 didn't update this change into .aspx file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: Nope, searching for `OnClick` came up empty.  I did this both in the `.aspx` file and in `web.config`.